# Python - Match Identical key and fetch corresponding value when we have duplicate keys

Tags: python

I am trying to match two files with identical name if present then corresponding output has to generate. But facing issue in fetching portName value in the
below code because PortName value is present in both the files.
Can anybody help me in resolving this code?

```
Input:
key2,val2
portIdentifyingName 1/1/2:12.*
portName Port 1/1/2

key3,val3
portName portIdentifyingName
parentInterface portName

Code:
for key2, val2 in new.items():
    for key3, val3 in val1.items():
        if key2 == val3:
            # print key2,key3
            # portIdentifyingName == portIdentifyingName
            self.json_dict[key3] = val2
            # Expected Output is portName = 1/1/2:12.*
            # Current Output is portName = Port 1/1/2
            # So adding extra code to satisfy that condition
            if 'portIdentifyingName' in val3:
                self.json_dict['portName'] = val2
                print self.json_dict['portName']
                portName Port 1/1/2
                
Expected Output:
portName 1/1/2:12.*
```